# Upgrade from Dojo 1.4 to 1.8

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I am working on the Migration of Dojo from 1.4 to 1.8. I have a project in which there are some jsp pages in which dojo is written and it takes the path of dojo from an xml file.
I have changed the path from dojo 1.4 Library to dojo 1.8 Library, but after doing this the referneces to the dojo widgets are throwing an error

e.g dijit.byId("idofwidget")

ERROR : dijit.byId("idofwidget") is null or not an object.

Please guide how to resolve the issue and it would be better if basics steps to upgrade can be provided.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

If you're really going to upgrade to Dojo 1.8, then you will have to rewrite your code into AMD, for example:

```js
// Load the modules you need
require([ "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dojo/parser" ], function(registry, ready) {

    // Wait until DOM is finished + widgets on the page are parsed
    ready(function() {

        // Retrieve widget instance
        registry.byId("idofwidget");
    });
});
```

One important thing to know is that you don't upgrade Dojo, you migrate it (at least when using pre- and post-1.7). This usually involves that you can not simply change the Dojo library, but you will have to migrate your code as well.

There are some articles about migrating from pre-1.7 to post-1.7, for example [this article about migrating](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-17.html).

Sitepen also provided a tool called the [Dojo AMD converter](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/04/03/introducing-dojo-amd-converter/) which can convert your modules into AMD syntax, it's not 100% guaranteed that it will work, but it puts you one step closer (at least). They also have an article about migrating, which you can find [here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/07/24/how-to-migrate-a-module-to-amd/).